# Environment containing fbox not working

Tags: environments

I have the following, which I intend using to render notes:

```
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}
\noindent
\fbox{
    \parbox{0.93\textwidth}{%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[height=40px]{images/note.png}
        \end{minipage}%
        \hfill%
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.8\textwidth}
            \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
            \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
            This is an example note, just to see how it renders and wraps lines and what-not.

            Here is another paragraph, yo.
        \end{minipage}
    }%
}
```

It looks pretty much how I want it, apart from the text not being centered (haven't figured that one out yet):

[image]

However, in trying to convert this into an environment, I am running into issues. For example, I tried converting just part of it thusly:

```
\newenvironment*{note}
{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
    \noindent%
    \begin{fbox}
    \begin{parbox}{0.93\textwidth}
%            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}
%                \includegraphics[height=40px]{images/note.png}
%            \end{minipage}%
%            \hfill%
%            \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
%                \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
%                \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
}
{
       \end{parbox}
    \end{fbox}
}
```

But this gives me errors when using the environment:

```
LaTeX Error: \begin{fbox} on input line 145 ended by \end{par
box}.
```

I got the tip to use `\begin{x}` and `\end{x}` in another question, but I don't understand why it's complaining about the above. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: You cannot just make environments out of commands and expect it to work. Neither `fbox` nor `parbox` are environments!

Comment: Ugh, LaTeX is kicking my butt. I spent over an hour tweaking that `fbox` code thinking I could use environments to save me copy+pasting it everywhere. I've been thinking of environments like methods - abstractions that create re-usable snippets of code. Apparently that's not the case, then.

Comment: LaTeX is mark-up by macro expansion. You should read an introduction. Being a programmer doesn't really help, imho.

Comment: @Johannes_B: It does help, in other contexts of LaTeX, but concerning expansion, being a programmer is an obstacle ;-)

Comment: Dp you really want to center the text in the box? This will look ugly in most cases. Centering one line (a heading) is alright, but centering text having than just one line is difficult to read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\fbox` and `\parbox` cannot be used this way as an environment, although `\begin{fbox}Foo\end{fbox}` would work, but only for the character `F`. It would work with `NewEnviron` and `\BODY` from the `environ` package, most likely.

I suggest to apply the `tcolorbox` environment and drawing the `pencil` image as an overlay (sidebyside would be possible as well). The `pencil` is the macro `\bccrayon` from the `bclogo` package, but it can be replaced by `\includegraphics{...}` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtcolorbox{note}[1][]{
  enhanced,
  halign=center,
  sharp corners,
  left=30pt,
  overlay={\node[below right] (crayon) at  ($(interior.north west)+(10pt,0)$) {\bccrayon};},
  #1
}



\begin{document}


\begin{note}[colback=yellow!20!white]
  \blindtext
  \vskip\baselineskip
  \blindtext
\end{note}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I think your approach of using overlays is better than mine. But which version of tcolorbox does this code require? When I am trying to run it I am getting a `I do not know the key '/tcb/halign'` error with version 3.21.

Comment: @jakun: According to the manual it was introduced on 2015-05-07, which is version 3.60

Comment: `tcolorbox` is just...wow. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

`\fbox` and `\parbox` are commands, no environments and can therefore not be used as environments.

If you want an environment producing fancy boxes I recommend taking a look at the [tcolorbox](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \newcommand{\iconwidth}{40px}%
    \newcommand{\iconsep}{1em}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\iconwidth+\iconsep}
        \includegraphics[width=\iconwidth, align=t, vshift=12pt]{images/note}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\iconwidth-\iconsep\relax}
        \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        This is an example note, just to see how it renders and wraps lines and what-not.

        Here is another paragraph, yo.
    \end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that I am using the graphbox package which is an extension of graphicx providing the `align` and `vshift` options for the `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: Well, principally `\begin{fbox}...\end{fbox}` works, but only for one token. This is by design of the environment starting and end codes

Comment: Yes, you are right. technically that works for a single token and even for more if you put them in surrounding characters of catcodes 1 and 2. But semantically that's wrong.

Comment: Yes, I know about that catcode characters, usually being `{` and `}` ... it's not only semantically wrong, it is also getting tedious to have `\begin{fbox}{foo text}\end{fbox}` all the time

Answer (score 1):

An answer just the way you tried but with environ package that gives the opportunity to use the body of the environment as `\BODY`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\NewEnviron{note}
{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
    \noindent%
    \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{
            \begin{minipage}[c]{0.1\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[height=40px]{example-image}
            \end{minipage}%
            \hfill%
            \begin{minipage}[c]{0.8\textwidth}
                \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
                \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
                \BODY
            \end{minipage}}}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{note}
  test text here that will be centered with the image or whatever you chose
\end{note}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]